# iOS IDFA: Firebase and Google Adwords Universal App Campaign Setup

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-ads-api, idfa

I am doing a UAC to promote my iOS app. Read through Google's documentation and still can't really understand how/when to use IDFA.

What I have done:
 - Added Firebase to my pod and did basic setup, so `first_open` events are
   tracked
 - Linked Firebase to Adwords
 - Setup UAC to count first_open as conversion

And my question is, what additional setup is required?
 - Do I need IDFA enabled to have Adwords recognize `first_open` events properly?
 - So I shall install the GoogleIDFASupport pod?
 - Then I use `advertisingIdentifier` of the `ASIdentifierManager` class to get the IDFA string? Then what? How do I get Adwords and Firebase to know a `first_open` is associated with a particular IDFA?

If IDFA is not needed, how does Google know if a `first_open` event is a new installation resulting from UAC, instead of an existing user upgrading or reinstalling the app directly from App Store?

Thanks for all the help, first day into this and it's all very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

The steps are:

1. Add Firebase to pod, launch in simulator, check in the Firebase
   dashboard that first_open event is showing
2. Link Firebase to Adwords (has to be under same google account)
3. Setup UAC to count first_open as conversion.
4. [important] Make sure you have app id (123456789) added in in Firebase project settings.

Done

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue.

I found this thread to be very informative and will possibly help some... but not me:
https://support.google.com/google-ads/thread/13548280?hl=en

It was an incomplete app profile in the Firebase settings.

The gear next to "Project Overview" > General > Your apps > iOS apps

I was missing App Store ID (in your apps store URL) and Team ID (in your Apple Developer Membership Details).

Once those were filled out I returned to GoogleAds and found that I could now import all my iOS events (Conversions > Plus menu...).